# Слово "помпа"

Tags: этимология

Говорят "сделать что-то с помпой" или "помпезное сооружение". Помпа - это насос. Но при чем тут насос в значении "излишне монументальный", "громкий"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова никоим образом не родственны.
Насос (обычно - морской) идет от голландского pomp с тем же значением.
А вот "помпа", "помпезный" восходит к греческому "pompa" - торжественное шествие. 
Кстати, ваше толкование "излишне монументальный" слишком узко. Помпа, по словарю Кузнецова, - внешняя, показная пышность, торжественность.

А вот касательно "помпезного сооружения", то тут ещё возможно ошибочное смешение с "помпадур" - стиль в архитектуре, мебели, оформлении интерьеров. Он отличается игривостью,  причудливой декорированностью. Это, правда, тоже совсем не монументальность, но и не совсем "помпезность". Т.е. в данном случае - случайное созвучие, но оно иногда вводит в заблуждение.